# How to bind a key inside the completing-read prompt?

Tags: key-bindings, ido, minibuffer

In one of my packages, I use a loop with `completing-read` to query the user for a list of words. Inside the prompt, I'd like to bind `DEL` to a different command.

**How can I achieve that?**

The solution also needs to work with `ido-completing-read` (possibly with small modifications of course).

Answer (score 1):

There are of course keymaps you can bind stuff to. For example you could temporarily merge *minibuffer-local-filename-completion-map* with your extra keys. From the documentation:

```
Local keymap for minibuffer input with completion for filenames.
Gets combined either with `minibuffer-local-completion-map' or
with `minibuffer-local-must-match-map'.
```

Comment: Will this keymap be applied even if my prompts have nothing to do with filenames?

Answer (score 1):

Just have your *command* bind the key you want in the appropriate minibuffer keymap, and then unbind it there when the command is done.

[You do not need to merge keymaps. You just need to bind the key in a map that is already being used (whether it was merged or not).]

The minibuffer keymaps that involve completion (depending on your Emacs version):

```
minibuffer-local-completion-map  
minibuffer-local-filename-completion-map
minibuffer-local-filename-must-match-map        
minibuffer-local-must-match-filename-map
minibuffer-local-must-match-map
```